# How to return list of multiple objects from a function in R?

Tags: r, list, function

I'd like to input a list of multiple training and testing data frames into a function where I manipulate the data, perform regressions, etc. and then output the results as a list of objects or data frames.

Here's a simple coding example with toy data:

```
# Create sample datasets
  train1 <- data.frame(y=c(1,2,3),x=c(10,20,30))
  train2 <- data.frame(y=c(2,3,4),x=c(15,25,35))
  train3 <- data.frame(y=c(3,4,5),x=c(20,30,40))
  test1 <- data.frame(y=c(2,3,4),x=c(15,25,35))
  test2 <- data.frame(y=c(3,4,5),x=c(25,35,45))
  test3 <- data.frame(y=c(4,5,6),x=c(35,45,55))

# Gather train & test datasets into list and initialize output_list
  train_subset <- mget(paste0("train", 1:3), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  test_subset <- mget(paste0("test", 1:3), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  output_list <- setNames(lapply(1:3, function(i) list()), paste0('output_', 1:3))

f <-   function(a,b,c) 
{
  a$log_y <- log(a$y)
  trainy <- c(log(a$y))
  testx <- data.matrix(b)
  list_i <- list(trainy, testx)
  return(output_list <<- list(c, list_i))
}

mapply(f, train_subset, test_subset, output_list, SIMPLIFY=F)
```

Which prints the following:

```
$train1
$train1[[1]]
list()

$train1[[2]]
$train1[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0.0000000 0.6931472 1.0986123

$train1[[2]][[2]]
     y  x
[1,] 2 15
[2,] 3 25
[3,] 4 35

$train2
$train2[[1]]
list()

$train2[[2]]
$train2[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0.6931472 1.0986123 1.3862944

$train2[[2]][[2]]
     y  x
[1,] 3 25
[2,] 4 35
[3,] 5 45

$train3
$train3[[1]]
list()

$train3[[2]]
$train3[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1.098612 1.386294 1.609438

$train3[[2]][[2]]
     y  x
[1,] 4 35
[2,] 5 45
[3,] 6 55
```

However only `trainy` and `testx` for train3 and test3 were saved into the `output_list` object - train1, test1, train2, and test2 are missing:

```
> output_list
[[1]]
list()

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1.098612 1.386294 1.609438

[[2]][[2]]
     y  x
[1,] 4 35
[2,] 5 45
[3,] 6 55
```

How do I return a list containing all of the output vectors and matrices from the function?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing `return(output_list <<- list(c, list_i))` instead of just returning the list?

Comment: @Dason That was my attempt to iteratively compile the trainy and testx output for each of the three iterations of the function into one global list, but obviously it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I found a simple solution - I'll post here in case there is interest:

```
f <- (function(a,b) 
    {
      trainy <- c(log(a$y))
      trainx <- data.matrix(a)
      testx <- data.matrix(b)
      list_i <<- list(trainy, testx)
    })

fit <- mapply(f,train_subset,test_subset)
```

where the object `fit` is a 2x3 matrix containing the trainy and testx output.